# Capybara/Cucumber : RoutingError for nested resources in a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I'm using Capybara/Cucumber on Rails 3.2 and I'm facing a weird routing error.

I have the following routes defined :

```
  #routes.rb
  namespace :super_user do
    ...
    resources :events do
      resources :invites
    end
  end
  ...
  resources :invites
```

and the following Cucumber feature :

```
@in_progress @current
Scenario: I can invite a USER by email
    Given the following event exists:
    | Name          |
    | The Event     |
    And I go to the event page for "The Event"
    And I follow "Invite new user"
    And I fill in "invite_email" with "user@domain.com"
    ...
```

The event page (`EventsController#show`) contains a link to the `invites#new` action :

```
#app/views/super_user/events/show.html.erb
...
<%= content_for :button_bar do %>
  <%= link_to( 'Invite new user', new_super_user_event_invite_path(@event) ) %>
<% end %>
```

Everything is working properly when I test the `/super_user/events/1` action manually, but whenever I run cucumber I get :

```
And I follow "Invite new user" # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:45
  uninitialized constant SuperUser::InvitesController (ActionController::RoutingError)
  (eval):2:in `click_link'
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:46:in `/^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/'
  features/create_casino_super_user.feature:24:in `And I follow "Invite new user"'
```

Why does routing behave differently when using Cucumber/Capybara ? How could I fix this feature ?

Relevant parts of `bundle list` :

```
* cucumber (1.0.6)
* cucumber-rails (1.0.2)
* capybara (1.0.1)
* capybara-webkit (0.6.1 dfa0624)
* rails (3.2.1)
```

**EDIT**

Side note : the InvitesController class is not in the SuperUser module but as I said previously it works when testing manually.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Rails 3 (not 3.2), coming from 2.3 and just jumping to the new routing DSL. I came across a very similar issue where our resource-in-a-namespace routes work when hit directly but not from inside Cucumber/Capybara.

In the end, I pulled the default routes from Rails 2.3 and made them active only inside cucumber, which seems to work:

```
# Cucumber doesn't understand the Rails 3 default route, above, so use the old way to make that work
# TODO remove this when we can/must, and hope that Cucumber is smarter by then
if File.basename($0) == "cucumber"
    map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
    map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
end
```

Not sure that's an option for you (`map.connect` is part of the old API, which I think disappears in 3.1), but I wanted to put it on the internet somewhere for those who come looking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1). As you said `map.connect` is now deprecated. The only solution I found was to create a base controller (`InvitesControllerBase`) and extended it in the namespaced `SuperUser::InvitesController` class.